# HBase Bulk Load jar issue

Tags: hbase

I am trying to do Bulk Load in Hbase. But I am confused which jar should I use for the below command:

```
hadoop jar /usr/lib/hbase/hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.3.0-security.jar importtsv
```

When I execute this command there is a java class not find exception .
My Hbase version is hbase-0.98.5-hadoop1. I am not able to find the correct jar for running the above command, and I cant find `hbase-0.94.6-cdh4.3.0-security.jar` in my hbase-0.98.5-hadoop1/lib folder . Is there an equivalent jar for `hbase-0.98.5-hadoop1` version of hbase . I am new to bulk load so please excuse me if I am asking an odd question

Comment: Hi, I am stuck with this for a couple of days . Anyone know this answer?

Comment: What is the class which is not found?

Comment: which jar is generally used for Bulk Load? In my hbase version I cant find the suitable jar.

Comment: I also have hbase 0.98.5 but I havent tried it since i have been using apache phoenix. what i am asking is, what is the class which is not found?

Comment: it shows mapreduce.Driver class is missing . But I used **hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,f:count wordcount word_count.csv**  command .Now it shows ERROR: No columns specified. Please specify with -Dimporttsv.columns=... Usage: importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c <tablename> <inputdir> this exception

Comment: please check if hbase lib has all nessessary hadoop libs

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you have the path for hbase in the classpath you can directly run it like this:

> hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv
>   -Dimporttsv.skip.bad.lines=true -Dimporttsv.columns="$columns" $table_name $file

Comment: **hbase org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=HBASE_ROW_KEY,f:count wordcount word_count.csv**   i tried this command .But the below exception is shown:
**ERROR: No columns specified. Please specify with -Dimporttsv.columns=...
Usage: importtsv -Dimporttsv.columns=a,b,c <tablename> <inputdir>**

I just have one columnfamily 'f'. Is there anything wrong with the command i used?

Comment: please check the syntax, you have specified importtsv after org.apache.hadoop.hbase.mapreduce.ImportTsv, which you shouldn't do

Comment: Yes. The error is gone now. I have loaded the data from the file using Bulk load. Thanks :)

Comment: great !! ...could you please mark the question as answered